# Angular 8 Carousel : Download Image button on each slide

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, download, carousel

I'm working with Angular 8 **Carousel** using Angular select plugin. I need to display some pictured in it with a download button to **download** the image directly. Can somebody help me with suggestions on how to do it? Carousel is working fine but I'm unable to add the download button.

Comment: can you share a stackblitz with your current logic and progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[w3 Carousel Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

And you can use angular click event some tag in *ngFor

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let photo of photos">
    <img [src]="photo?.url" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 (click)="download(photo)">Download</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```